# How to attach a picture to an email?

Tags: abap

I'd like to attach a picture to an email. The picture was sent by API from a mobile application. The picture received is of string type (base64) and is to be displayed in the email body (HTML). The problem is, the email is succesfully sent but the picture is not displayed.

```
CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_STRING_TO_XSTRING'
EXPORTING
  text   = i_pict
IMPORTING
  buffer = p_bmp_xstream
EXCEPTIONS
  failed = 1
  OTHERS = 2.

IF SY-SUBRC <> 0.
* MESSAGE ID SY-MSGID TYPE SY-MSGTY NUMBER SY-MSGNO
*         WITH SY-MSGV1 SY-MSGV2 SY-MSGV3 SY-MSGV4.
ENDIF.

PT_SOLIX = CL_BCS_CONVERT=>XSTRING_TO_SOLIX( P_BMP_XSTREAM ).
```

What I tried is convert it first into XSTRING then convert it in SOLIX.

Comment: You are guessing that the issue comes only from the piece of code you are providing and not from the part where you build the email. Could you explain why? If you think that it might possibly come from the code which builds the email then could you paste this piece of code also.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across the same kind of requirement before and I took help from this link below and it worked for me.

There are two important things to do to show an image along with the email text (note : the image must not be passed as an attachment, that would force the user to open the attachment to see the image):

- Your text must be passed in HTML format
- Inside HTML, you may define the image with base64 as follows : `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KG...>` (iVBORw0KG... to be replaced by your image base64 characters)

The main method used in the link below to create the email is :

```
cl_document_bcs=>create_document( 
     i_type = 'HTM' 
     i_text = table_of_HTML_code 
     ... ).
```

Take a look at the below link, if it doesn't help lets discuss further.
http://saptechnical.com/Tutorials/ABAP/email/Index.htm

Comment: Please "add a context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there" ([FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)) More details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) how to better answer.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me @SandraRossi, Am a newbie in here! will for sure keep this in mind.

Comment: We were all newbies here at the beginning, and we were all being "advised" by elders ;)

Comment: Thanks! for being kind and am happy that someone is there to hold my back!

Comment: Not sure if you were about to edit your answer, so let me show you what is expected ("adding a context around the link..." as I said). Feel free to edit it at your convenience.